# Did Rex have a legit battle plan going against the AT-ATs?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

When Rex charged his AT-TE against Agent Kallus' AT-ATs, he "go for the legs" in classic fashion. However, being outflanked by the second walker notwithstanding, he had trouble lifting the first walker up, let alone topple it. He did know that he can exploit the vulnerable neck with his main cannon if the opportunity presents itself, however.

Did he actually have a legit plan to win, and how? Or did he go in as a last stand to help the Ghost crew escape, expecting to be KIA?